# When to use standard error in normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I am having issues understanding why you wouldn't use the standard error instead.

Question:

The actual weight, $X$ kilograms, of fertilizer in a 5 kg bag may be modeled by a
normal random variable with mean $5.25$ and standard deviation $0.20$ .

The part i) to the question asks to calculate the probability that weight is between $P(5.1 < X < 5.3)$ which was calculated correctly to be $0.372$.

Part ii) then went along the lines of:

A random sample of four $5 kg$ bags is selected. Calculate the probability that none
of the $four$ bags contains between $5.1 kg$ and $5.3 kg$ of fertilizer.

Could someone explain to me why there would be no need to use standard error given that it is a sample? Shouldn't the question ask for each $individual$ bag of the 4 instead (I don't know if I'm not interpreting the question correctly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the standard error because you are not doing a calculation regarding the **mean of a sample**.

Instead you just need $(1-0.372)^4$

Comment: I see, so when the question states that we are calculating the probability of a sample mean, then we use standard error?

Comment: Yes that's right